# While truncating a table under a keyspace in cassandra its throwing "Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily test "

Tags: cassandra

While truncating a table in cassandra i am getting a response

use mig_vuc;

cqlsh:mig_vuc> TRUNCATE test;

**Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily test**

But I can see the test table is created :

cqlsh:mig_vuc> DESCRIBE TABLES;

test test1 test2

Comment: Please use cassandra cli to over come this issue .

Comment: check for the cassandra status before using the command ! !